# Expanding macro globally: is it possible to automate?

Tags: c++, macros, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on a really crappy codebase. To give you an idea, here's how they do loops:

```
#define loop(v,m) for(int v = 0; v < int(m); ++v)
```

This is done everywhere. And it gets even worse:

```
#define loopi(m) loop(i, m)
#define loopj(m) loop(j, m)
#define loopk(m) loop(k, m)
#define loopl(m) loop(l, m)
#define looprev(v, m) for (int v = int(m); --v >= 0;)
#define loopirev(m) looprev(i, m)
#define loopjrev(m) looprev(j, m)
#define loopkrev(m) looprev(k, m)
#define looplrev(m) looprev(l, m)
```

I have tried Eclipse's macro expansion refactoring tool, but it crashes. Is there a tool that can help me with this? This is just one of the hundreds of macros like this.

Comment: Regex Replace: `loop([A-Za-z]{1})\\(([A-Za-z]{1})\\)`  -> `for\\(int $1 = 0; $1 < $2; \\+\\+$1\\)`

Regex Replace: `loop\\(([A-Za-z]{1}), ([A-Za-z]{1})\\)` -> `""`

Comment: Not really reliable. You can have complex expressions inside the parenthesis. Like: loopi(func() + 2)

Comment: (i already tried hand-made regexes) :(

Comment: What is "Eclipse's macro expansion refactoring tool"?

Comment: If you have a macro, right click + quick fix. It will suggest an expansion.

Comment: I feel for ya, but this question is out of scope for SO. See our [help].

Comment: All I see after right click + quick fix is "Rename in file" and "Rename in workspace". Perhaps you mean right + click + Explore Macro Expansion?

Comment: @vinnylinux

"If you have a macro, right click + quick fix. It will suggest an expansion. "

Do you have any 3rd party plug-ins installed, my CDT does not have this feature. If it is the "Explore Macro Expansion" crashing, can you provide more details? Perhaps in a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) :-)

Comment: https://www.cevelop.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built-in way to automate this with Eclipse CDT.

You could probably write an Eclipse plugin to automate it, although if manually invoking "Explore Macro Expansion" (I assume that's what you're referring to in your question) crashes, then your plugin is likely to run into the same crash. I would suggest [filing a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) about that crash either way.

You could also look into other tools like [clang-expand](https://github.com/goldsborough/clang-expand).